# TSaveDialog change the case of the filename

Tags: windows, winapi, lazarus

I use TSaveDialog in Lazarus 1.6.4 (Windows 7). If in the dialog you enter the file name: "TEST.txt" but the file exists with the name "test.txt", then the SaveDialog1.FileName field will contain the value: "C:\test.txt". If no such file exists, the SaveDialog1.FileName field will contain exactly the value that was entered (in the same case): SaveDialog1.FileName = "C:\TEST.txt". Is there any way to change this behavior? I need the case of characters not to change anyway.

Comment: “*I need the case of the characters not to change anyway*” - why? What is so special about preserving the case, especially on an OS that uses a case-insensitive file system?

Comment: Later, I modify the filename if it was entered in uppercase, so I need to know this information.

Comment: What you describe is standard behavior. If a file already exists, the existing filename is returned as-is. So again, I ask, WHY do you want to preserve the case of the input rather than the case of the existing file? What are you really trying to accomplish? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: If the system is already set up to work in a particular way, it's often best to adapt your envisaged solution to the system. Can you do that here?